# Inflate layouts in app using ViewPageIndicator library

Tags: android, swap

I am reading about using ViewPageIndicator library [from here](http://viewpagerindicator.com/#introduction)

and I can see in my application the swapping works. I don't understand the entire library code and I am trying to inflate my own views for each of the "page indicator" and i don't know how.
In the ViewPagerAdapter class there is this method:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
    //TextView v = new TextView(context);
    //v.setText(titles[position]);
    //((ViewPager) pager).addView(v, 0);

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekevents, null);
     ((ViewPager) pager).addView(view,1);
    return view;
}
```

Should I understand that i should inflate my layouts here? I have a layout for each page that i am swapping. If i inflate the layout weekevents nothing happends.
I did not post any code because it's the same from the above link.
And now I am trying to understand how to work with this.
Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that you shall override  instantiateItem()   and inflate proper layout for each page.  ( if position is 1, inflate this layout , if position is 2 inflate another etc. ).

Above code snippet does not discriminate resources based on position.

Comment: hm, thx :) Wouldn't i return only one specific view, even if i have more? like this:                                      `LayoutInflater weekInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View viewWeek = weekInflater.inflate(R.layout.weekevents, null);
  ((ViewPager) pager).addView(viewWeek, 0);

  LayoutInflater dayInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View viewDay = dayInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayevents, null);
  ((ViewPager) pager).addView(viewDay, 1);
  return viewWeek;`

Comment: It requests you to initialize view for specific position in pager - so you just deliver it.  It is the same pattern like list adapter -  it asks you for view suitable for item number x - you inflate and set it up